# How to move a custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

Basically my question is: **how to move a complete `view` around, instead of just moving the `canvas`?** **I have a custom `view` and I want to move the whole thing not just the `canvas`.**

This is what I have tried, but I get a `NullPointerException` (the code is not compleate, I have put what I think is the most relevant part, also the parent of the custom `view` is a `LinearLayout`):

ResistorView class:

```
LinearLayout root;

public class ResistorView extends View{

    public ResistorView(Context context){
        super(context);         
        root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        

    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
    }
    root.invalidate(); //There is a NullPointerException on this line.
    return true;
    }
```

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="Add RES" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, if someone can help I would really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you moving it around *in*?

Comment: The view is inside a linear layout, so I guess I would move it inside a linear layout.

Comment: Looks like the parent is a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I edited to add the main.xml layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
```

to

```
root = (LinearLayout)getParent();
```

You may even want to do this inside of onTouch instead and remove it from the constructor, something like:

```
if(root == null) {
    root = (LinearLayout)getParent();
}
root.invalidate();
```

Comment: BTW - Is this a class inside an Activity? If so, make sure you are calling `View#getParent()` NOT `Activity#getParent()` Also if it is, it may also explain why its broken. Chances are you calling `View#findViewById()` instead of `Activity#findViewById()` in your constructor.

Comment: Wao, thanks. That solved the problem. Amazing how small things like that can make a big difference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using FrameLayout and call myCustomView.setX(x) and myCustomView.setY(y)
x and y passed to methods are event rawX and rawY + deltaX and deltaY

ACTION_DOWN case

```
deltaX = v.x - event.rawX
deltaY = v.y - event.rawY
```

deltaX and deltaY are global variables

and in ACTION_MOVE case do this

```
v.x = event.rawX + deltaX
v.y = event.rawY + deltaY
```